# sqlite3_column_text() type conversion

Tags: c++, sqlite

```
const unsigned char* sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3 stmt*, int iCol);
```

A pointer to a c-string is returned and the string shall not be modified. Yet I make such conversion:

```
char* str = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3 stmt*, int iCol);
```

Do not get any run-time problems even if the string gets thoroughly mutilated. I am still bit nervous about that `const` thing. Why is it there? Any problems I may run into?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of SQLite, the return value happens to point into a buffer that is used exlusively for the cursor's row, but there is no guarantee that this is actually the case, or that it will continue to be.

The returned value might point to the memory-mapped database file itself, in which case your modifications would corrupt it. Or the library might implement a shared-string dictionary to save memory, in which case your modifications would affect all rows in the database with similar text. Or the buffer might be write-protected by the MMU, in which case your code attempting to write to it would crash.

In any case, the `const` clearly shows that you are not allowed to modify the returned string, so you should not even try.